# Laravel - The page you are looking for could not be found

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404

I got page 404 when I click the link

I don't know which part is wrong, can someone help me?

**sidenav**

```
<a href="{{ route('posts.indexRequest') }}">Request List</a>
```

**route**

```
Route::prefix('dashboard')->middleware('role:superadministrator|administrator|editor|author|contributor')->group( function () {
  Route::get('/', 'PagesController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');
  Route::resource('/posts', 'PostController');
  Route::get('/posts/request-list', 'PostController@indexRequest')->name('posts.indexRequest');
});
```

**Post Controller**

```
public function indexRequest()
{
  $posts = Post::where('status', 'On Request')->orderBy('created_at')->paginate(12);

  return view('manages.posts.request', compact('posts'));
}
```

**and I have the view**

[image: Folder Structure]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot set a get route after a resource route if they use the same prefix.

The resource route will define `posts/{post}` as the `PostController@show` route, equivalent to:

```
Route::get('posts/{post}', 'PostController@show')
```

This will conflict with your bottom route and `posts/request-list` and will evaluate `request-list` as a post ID ({post}) in the above route.

Set all specific routes before resource routes.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that before

Answer (score 0):

did you try to direct access to your "app-link/posts/request-list"

Comment: @SilentK1D, avoid posting answers that are clarifying questions.  Once you have reputation here, you can ask these questions in the comments, but this is not an answer.